# std::find() on a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, find

I want to search through a vector of pointers to and compare the pointers to an `int`. My initial idea was to use `std::find()` but i realized that I cannot compare a pointer to an `int`.

Example:

```
if(std::find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 0) != myvector.end()
{
   //do something
}
```

`myvector` is a vector containing pointers to a class object, i.e., `vector<MyClass*> myvector`.`MyClass` contains a method `getValue()` which will return an integer value and I basically want to go through the vector and check each object's `getValue()` return value to determine what i do.

Using the previous example:

```
if(std::find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 0) != myvector.end()
{
   //Output 0
}
else if(std::find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 1) != myvector.end()
{
   //Output 1
}
else if(std::find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 2) != myvector.end()
{
   //Output 2
}
```

Its almost like an absolute condition where if any pointer's value in my vector is a 0, i output zero, i output 0. If no zero is found, i look to see if there is a 1. If 1 is found, i output 1. Etc, etc..

Comment: `getValue()` is a `const` function right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `std::find_if()` instead.  The other answers show how to use a lambda for the predicate, but that only works in C++11 and later.  If you are using an earlier C++ version, you can do this instead:

```
struct isValue
{
    int m_value;

    isValue(int value) : m_value(value) {}

    bool operator()(const MyClass *cls) const
    {
        return (cls->getValue() == m_value);
    }
};

...

if (std::find_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), isValue(0)) != myvector.end()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution as i am using an earlier version of C++. Can you explain the `struct isValue` more? I do know see where i would use it.

Comment: The `isValue` struct is being used as a `std::find_if()` predicate: `std::find_if(..., isValue(0))`. A new instance of the struct is constructed with the desired comparison value and then that instance is passed to `std::find_if()`. The predicate accepts anything that can be called using `result = predicate(params)` syntax, which includes ordinary functions, objects with an overridden `operator()`, lambdas, etc.

Comment: I get the following error: `error: passing 'const MyClass' as 'this' argument of 'char MyClass::getValue()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]` I pretty much copied what you wrote.

Comment: If `getValue()` is not declared as a `const` method of `MyClass` (eg: `int getValue() const`) then drop the `const` from the `cls` parameter of `bool operator()`, eg: `bool operator()(MyClass *cls) const`.

Answer (score 11):

What you want is `std::find_if` and a custom compare function/functor/lambda.  With the custom comparator you can call the correct function to do the comparison.  Something like

```
std::find_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](MyClass* e) { return e->getValue() == 0; })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::find_if` which relies on a predicate rather than a value

```
if(std::find_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](MyClass* my) { return my->getValue() == 0; }) != myvector.end()
{
   //Output 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler that you want to call `getValue()` on each pointer, and that's the thing you're searching for. `std::find()` is only for matching values, for anything more complicated, there's [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::find_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(),
    [](const MyClass* c) { return c->getValue() == 0; }
);
```