# How do you check if a derived class object is already being stored in a vector?

Tags: c++, object, search, vector, polymorphism

I'm trying to create an inventory system for a text based game. I'm currently working on the function that adds objects that were derived from a class called Items to a vector and then call a function from the derived class to update its quantity. I was able to do that fairly easily, but I want to add some checks in the function so instead of adding a duplicate object into the vector it would find the duplicate object and call its function that updates its quantity.

I tried doing this but the program would crash when ever the program got to delete. So I decided to try and removing delete and was able to call the function showInventory() and got very strange results.

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a class object is already being stored in a vector and if it is return the elements posistion in the vector so I can use the objects addQuant() function so I can update its quantity

`std::vector<Items*> inv;`

```
void Inventory::AddtoInv( Items* s)
{
    if (!inv.empty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++)
        {
            if (inv[i]->getName() == s->getName())
            {
                inv[i]->addQuant();
                delete s;
            }
            else
            {
                s->addQuant();
                inv.push_back(s);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        s->addQuant();
        inv.push_back(s);
    }
}

void Inventory::ShowInv()
{
    std::cout << "your inventory" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < inv.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << inv[i]->getName() << "    x" << inv[i]->showQuant() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I also tried this but std::find() doesn't find the object.

```
if (std::find(inv.begin(), inv.end(), s) != inv.end())
{

    std::cout << "you already have this item" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    inv.push_back(s);
    std::cout << "added item: " << s->getName << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You have a vector of pointers, so he default behaviour of `std::find(inv.begin(), inv.end(), s)` is going to be comparing pointers. If the addresses aren't the same, you don't have the same instance, no matter how similar the contents of the objects at the pointers are they won't match.  That makes this question a duplicate of [std::find() on a vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490173/stdfind-on-a-vector-of-pointers)

Comment: What does the code look like that is calling `AddtoInv()`?

Comment: Please explain to your rubber duck what happens in `AddtoInv` if `inv` already contains four pointers and `s` has the same name as the third element.

Comment: @RemyLebeau its used in a case, so case 1: inv.AddtoInv(new Grain) it's passing in a child of the Items class.

Comment: Using `new` directly in a function parameter like that is bad practice. If `AddtoInv()` throws an exception (like on `inv.push_back()`), then you leak memory. In this situation, consider using `std::unique_ptr<Items>` for the `AddtoInv()` parameter, and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Items>>` for the `inv`. That way, there is no question about who owns what. And you gain automated destruction of the inventory items when `inv` is cleared or destroyed, so you don't have to do it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AddtoInv()` function can be simplified to this:

```
Items* Inventory::GetfromInv(const string &name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inv.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (inv[i]->getName() == name)
            return inv[i];
    }

    /* alternatively:

    auto iter = std::find_if(inv.begin(), inv.end(), [&](Items *item){ return (item->getName() == name); });
    if (iter != inv.end())
        return *iter;
    */

    return 0;
}

void Inventory::AddtoInv( Items* s)
{
    Items *item = GetfromInv(s->getName());
    if (!item)
    {
        inv.push_back(s);
        item = s;
    }
    else
        delete s;

    item->addQuant();
}
```

That being said, getting crashes on `delete`, and weird results from `showInv()`, implies that you are not managing your pointers correctly.  Such as if you are destroying objects that are stilling being pointed to by the `inv` vector.  But you didn't show any of the code that is calling `AddInv()` or otherwise using the inventory, so we can't help you diagnose any issues you may have in that code.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! someone suggested using std::find_if, is there any advantage or disadvantage  of using this over find_if or vice versa?

Comment: `std::find_if()` and `find_if()` are the same function. The latter will compile only if you have a `using namespace std;` statement (which you shoudn't be using) or a `using std::find_if;` statement

Comment: I meant the advantage or disadvantage of using find_if over the code you posted?

Comment: `std::find_if()` is a standardized algorithm in the STL, why duplicate the same work that has already been done for you?